# Create new column in pandas dataframe using if statement against another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate a new column in my dataframe using a if in the calculation but have no luck with anything I have tried. This is what I have

```
     OrderNum  Discount  OrderQty  UnitPrice  REMAININGQTY
0    115702       0.0      25.0     145.00          25.0
1    115793       0.0      20.0     823.00          20.0
2    115793       0.0      20.0     823.00          20.0
3    116282       0.0       1.0     699.95           1.0
4    116765       0.0      36.0     295.00           6.0
```

This is what I need.

column = PricePer

the calculation = `IIf(df.discount<>0,df.unitprice-(df.discount/df.orderqty),df.unitprice)`

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What does `df.discount<>0` mean?  Also for this section, `Discount` is always 0, so you're always producing `unitprice` anyways

Comment: In this example it is but from time to time there are discounts. So it will change from 0.0 to a value of .25 or whatever the discount is.

Comment: `import numpy as np
df['NEW VARIABLE']=np.where([df['discount']!=0], df['UnitPrice']-(df['Discount']/df['OrderQty']),df['UnitPrice'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Price Per'] = pd.np.where(df.Discount != 0, df.UnitPrice - (df.Discount / df.OrderQty), df.UnitPrice)
```

Output:

```
  OrderNum  Discount  OrderQty  UnitPrice  REMAININGQTY  Price Per
0    115702       0.0      25.0     145.00          25.0     145.00
1    115793       0.0      20.0     823.00          20.0     823.00
2    115793       0.0      20.0     823.00          20.0     823.00
3    116282       0.0       1.0     699.95           1.0     699.95
4    116765       0.0      36.0     295.00           6.0     295.00
```

Comment: Make sure to import numpy as np, `import numpy as np`

Comment: Actually, you don't need import numpy when you us pd.np.... numpy is imported as part of the pandas import.  So you can do `pd.np.where.....`

Comment: Learned something new then as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might also use these 2 statements

```
df.loc[df['Discount'] == 0, 'PricePer'] = df['UnitPrice']
df.loc[df['Discount'] != 0, 'PricePer'] = df['UnitPrice']-df['Discount']/df['OrderQty']
```

But if discount equals zero, the -(discount / orderqty) would be zero, no if is needed ? So I would think this might also do:

```
df['PricePer'] = df['UnitPrice']-df['Discount']/df['OrderQty']
```